# Reverting to old Profile Page design

Tags: support, design, profile-page

**Note**: This is not a rant but trying to understand how to get back to what I had earlier. I am sure many people would like the new layout but I prefer the old one. I tried searching for the settings but I could not find it. Is there any setting that I can use to revert to old layout (display style)?

Currently it looks like

> [image]

I personally do not find it user friendly and would like to revert to what it was earlier?

**ANSWERS SECTION**

Earlier I could see compact version. Just the question title and now I see all the irrelevant info. It takes me more time to scroll through the recent answers. Is there a way I can disable the detailing?

> [image]

**REPUTATION**

Earlier I could see all the reputations date wise. Now there is no option to see that?

> [image]

Am I missing something here?

**EDIT**

After reading the comments, I believe it is not possible to revert to old style. In such a case, can something like the below would also be helpful? This keeps the new style and adds a minor functionality to it?

> [image]

And

> [image]

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible. [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049). Welcome to the future where everything is designed for vertical layout.

Comment: _"I am sure many people would like the new layout"_, [I'm not so sure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page).

Comment: @RafaelTavares: I was just being polite :D

Comment: *"I tried searching for the settings but I could not find it"* ... honestly, what sense would it make for the SO developers to provide such setting? Then they would need to support and maintain two layouts. Your only chance are custom stylings and scripts.

Comment: @Tom Worked for reddit. /shrug

Comment: Here is the [list of the all the issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372698/379623) encountered by different users which are being addressed one by one. You too can express your concerns out there.

Comment: @Tom there are sites that let you choose from multiple layouts. SO itself has the old mobile view (which is deprecated *but used by default* on mobile devices) as well as the full/responsive view. Yes, in this case one of these isn't supported, however it goes to show that it does exist. There are other websites that allow users to choose from multiple views. This idea isn't so outlandish.

Comment: That mobile view is *meant* to be dead now though, @VLAZ ,and it hasn't been maintained in some time (not since the responsive site has been pushed on us).

Comment: @Larnu - Yet; Is the only view that works 100% of the time on a brand new iPhone 13 max pro

Comment: @VLAZ We're still talking about Stack Overflow and when I keep in mind how open-minded the company is, in regard to our wishes and feature-requests, I don't see a chance that such a setting will ever exist. They may fix some details on new roll-outs, but that's about it with "listening to the community". And yes, I have a very pessimistic view :/.

Comment: The two infamous posts (sort of canonical) are *[New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049)* (-245. 2021-11-19) and *[Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/)* (-395. 2021-08-05. Unspecific title - AKA the "Vanity metrics" post). [Some rage quit over it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/374131#374131).

Comment: @Tom in the context of SO - yes, you are right. However, that requires keeping track of how SE have been operating recently in regards to updates. Not all people have. It is not at all unreasonable for somebody to be uninformed and thus have other expectations.

Comment: @Larnu "*That mobile view is meant to be dead now though*" yet if you go to the mobile site, it's loaded by default... Yes, I'm well aware that all the guidance about the mobile view is "Only use it to enter the full site" yet 1. It's still here 2. it's the default. 3. You have to literally go out of your way to find out you're not supposed to use it. 4. While out of your way, you need to find out how to stop using it. It might be dead but SE has used its corpse to erect a wall around the real site they apparently want users to visit.

Comment: Yes, I have complained about it previously that it's the default, and was told it would be gone by the new year, yet here we are, @VLAZ, still being forced to view it first. That does not change the fact that it's supposed to be dead. Why it's not, I don't know; that's a question for [meta.se].

Comment: I share a *substantial* amount of frustration with the recent changes to the profile pages. The changes made moderation work *much* harder. However, it's very likely that SE isn't done making changes to those pages. SE, unfortunately, chose to push out the changes shortly before they froze their code for the end of the year break. This caused the existing buggy state of the profile pages to be kept for much longer, which increased the negative impression and frustration. It's entirely unclear what additional changes they will make, but a complete reversion to the old layout is unlikely.

Comment: Even if there are no significant changes from SE forthcoming, people will create userscripts to change the pages into something that's dramatically more usable. Some userscripts have already been made, while other userscript writers are waiting for SE to get closer to a "final" version. Unfortunately, SE's use of Stacks and disdain for semantic CSS makes it *vastly* harder to create such changes and *dramatically* increases the amount of effort needed to adapt such changes for even small changes on SE's part. I know I've wasted *months* of effort doing that, just for the "responsive" changes.